# How to use format()?

Tags: python, format

My teacher gave me this assigment"Write a program that calculates the bill of sale for three items purchased. The cost of each item will be read from the user and stored into variables. The receipt will show the number of items purchased, the cost of each item, the average cost per item, the tax rate (.0825% in Texas), the tax amount, and the total cost" I'was able to do it with basic input and variables but i had some trouble when he asked me to use format() in the code because  there's always a different error. Here's my attempt.

```
cost_1 = float(input("Enter cost of item 1:"))
cost_2 = float(input("Enter cost of item 2:"))
cost_3 = float(input("Enter cost of item 3:"))
cost = ['cost_1', 'cost_2', 'cost_3']
sentence = 'Cost 1: {0} Cost 2: {1} Cost 3: {2}'.format(cost, float['cost_1'], cost, float['cost_2'], cost, float['cost_3'])
print(sentence)
Average_cost = float(cost_1 + cost_2 + cost_3)/3
Total_cost = float(cost_1 + cost_2 + cost_3)
print("Average cost:", Average_cost)
print("Total cost:", Total_cost)
Tax_rate = float(8.25)
print("Tax rate:", Tax_rate)
Taxes = float(Total_cost*Tax_rate/100)
print ("Taxes:",float(Taxes))
Total = Total_cost + Taxes
print("Total:", Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you the answer, but I will explain a couple things you are doing wrong.

```
cost_1 = float(input("Enter cost of item 1:"))
cost_2 = float(input("Enter cost of item 2:"))
cost_3 = float(input("Enter cost of item 3:"))
# below you are assigning strings  to the cost array, you should not have quotes here
cost = ['cost_1', 'cost_2', 'cost_3']
# below you are trying to format with three variables but are passing four. 
# you are also trying to access the float function as a dict type.  
sentence = 'Cost 1: {0} Cost 2: {1} Cost 3: {2}'.format(cost, float['cost_1'], 
cost, float['cost_2'], cost, float['cost_3'])
print(sentence)
# there is no need to constantly float variables that are float
Average_cost = float(cost_1 + cost_2 + cost_3)/3
# agagin
Total_cost = float(cost_1 + cost_2 + cost_3)
print("Average cost:", Average_cost)
print("Total cost:", Total_cost)
# a float number is already a float, you dont need to declare it as float
Tax_rate = float(8.25)
print("Tax rate:", Tax_rate)
Taxes = float(Total_cost*Tax_rate/100)
print ("Taxes:",float(Taxes))
Total = Total_cost + Taxes
print("Total:", Total)
```

I will give you a little help with the cost list.

```
items_count = 3
cost = []
for i in range(items_count):
     cost.append(float(input("enter price for item %d: " % (i+1))))
```

Also, there is a function called sum that will add up all the numbers in a list.  Here is a tutorial https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum